# Example of smooth function without compact support on open real interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

What is an explicit example of a smooth function on a real open interval that does *not* have compact support, i.e. for given $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, a function (in common notation)

$$f \in C^{\infty}((a,b))\setminus C_0^{\infty}((a,b))$$

More precisely, I have the following technical issue: the support of a function is defined as a closure, i.e.

$$\text{supp } f = \overline{\{x\in(a,b) \vert f(x)\neq 0\}}$$

Intuitively I would think that a function $g\in C_0^{\infty}((a,b))$ has to vanish at the boundaries $a,b$ (e.g. to use for integration by parts), but because of this formal closure, it can be non-zero on $(a,b)$ and $\overline{(a,b)}=[a,b]$ is compact. Thus a non-zero function on the interval $(a,b)$ is in $C_0^{\infty}((a,b))$.

Where is the mistake in this reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the closure $\overline{\{x\in(a,b) \vert f(x)\neq 0\}}$  is meant in the space you are working in and that is $(a,b)$. So $\overline{\{x\in(a,b) \vert f(x)\neq 0\}} \subset (a,b)$ has to hold. And if you have $g$ nonzero in whole $(a,b)$ than its support is $(a,b)$ but $(a,b)$ is not compact.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the closure

$$\overline{\{x \in (a,b); f(x) \neq 0\}}$$

is taken in $(a,b)$, i.e.

$$\text{supp} \, f = \{x \in (a,b); \exists (x_n)_n \in (a,b): f(x_n) \neq 0, x_n \to x\} \subseteq (a,b)$$

In particular, if a function is non-zero on $(a,b)$, then $\text{supp} \, f = (a,b)$, and this is obviously not compact.